# Heroku Django Deployment error : "port" option should be >= 0 and < 65536: null

Tags: django, heroku

I created a Django app an have created the `Procfile` and `requirements.txt`. However when I run the command

`heroku create`

I get the following error :

```
 ▸    "port" option should be >= 0 and < 65536: null
```

How to fix it?

Comment: Can you post the entire log of what happens copied from the terminal?

Comment: And show the procfile.

Comment: Procfile : `web: gunicorn myApp.wsgi`.
That was the only output when I ran `heroku create`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This had been a problem due to the proxy (stupid college). The problem was due to not including `http://` and `https://` in the environment vairables. To fix this use :

`export http_proxy='http://proxyIP:port'
 export https_proxy='https://proxyIP:port'`

Comment: I am getting the error message even after setting the proxy.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like it's a problem with your development machine. Try reinstalling Heroku.
Heroku create is for adding the heroku instance to your repo.
When you push the master branch to heroku it should work.

Comment: Man I reinstalled 3 times. Still getting the error.